# Mysql copying parent child data to another table with different parent child ids

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure similar to screenshot attached below.

[image: Click here to see the Example Table Structure]

I want to copy data from these tables to different tables with similar structure.

```
NEW_EMPLOYEE
NEW_EMPLOYEE_COURSE_COMPLETION
NEW_EMPLOYEE_COURSE_COMPLETION_SUPPORTING_DOCUMENTS
```

I am currently using cursor to copy the data to `NEW_xxx` tables.

I am just wondering if this causes any performance issues or any other better approach. Please share thoughts and I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Note: Primary keys from the original tables are not copied. They will be generated in the NEW_xxx tables. But the mapping should be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `original_ID` column to each of the new tables, to hold the mappings as rows are copied. I assume the `ID` columns are `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. The `SELECT` query can join with the `NEW_EMPLOYEE` table to map the original employee IDs to the new IDs.

```
INSERT INTO NEW_EMPLOYEE (original_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, D_O_B)
SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, D_O_B
FROM EMPLOYEE;

INSERT INTO NEW_EMPLOYEE_COURSE_COMPLETION (original_ID, employee_id, course_id)
SELECT ecc.id, ne.id, ecc.course_id
FROM EMPLOYEE_COURSE_COMPLETION AS ecc
JOIN NEW_EMPLOYEE AS ne ON ecc.employee_id = ne.original_id;

INSERT INTO NEW_EMPLOYEE_COURSE_COMPLETION_SUPPORTING_DOCUMENTS (original_id, employee_course_completion_id, document_id)
SELECT eccsd.id, ne.id, eccsd.employee_course_completion_id, eccsd.document_id
FROM EMPLOYEE_COURSE_COMPLETION AS eccsd
JOIN NEW_EMPLOYEE AS ne ON eccsd.employee_id = ne.original_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That works just fine for the EMPLOYEE table. But then how do we retain the mapping while inserting the child records?

Comment: This copies all the IDs, so the mapping should be the same.

Comment: Correct. But we don’t copy the ID value. Apologies, should have mentioned about it before. Primary keys are created in the NEW_xxx tables.

Comment: Can you add an `original_id` column to the new table? You need something to hold the mapping between old and new IDs. If not, you'll have to use your cursor method that creates the rows one by one.

Comment: Yes I can definitely a new column to the new table. Could you please provide a sample query using original_id? Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate the help.